# Developing rails engines and using the asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, asset-pipeline, rails-engines

So I've started building a gem, which is difficult, but it seems to be working out so far..
Except for one little thing, the assets. I've tried putting them in my `lib/assets`, `app/assets` and `vendor/assets`. But they don't seem to load.

I have a test-app which loads my gem to test it, but nothing seems to work. I have an engine in my gem which I'm sure is being loaded.

What more do I need to know for this to start working?

EDIT:

here is my engine (located in `lib/baco/engine.rb`):

```
require 'rails'

module Baco

  class Engine < Rails::Engine

  end

end
```

EDIT 2:

This is my css file (located in `vendor/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss`):

```
/*
     * This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory
     * and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
     * the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
     *= require_self
     *= require baco
*/

input {
    padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: Rats, I was hoping that was the problem. You have the vendor folder at root of the Gem (not in lib)? And how are you referencing the assets inside the Gem?

Comment: Yes, I have a file called `application.css.scss` located in `vendor/assets/stylesheets`

Comment: Is there a good way for debugging this? For example tracing al the paths that are used by the asset pipeline..?

Comment: You can check the asset path by firing up the Rails Console and executing `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I still need to require the the css from the app that is loading the gem..

Is this a normal situation? Because I haven't read about that anywhere..

Anyways, got it to work, thanks for looking into it, hope this topic can helps some others out..

Comment: Yes, that is the normal behavior.